# Low quality accepted answer on a closed question

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, low-quality

I've seen a few examples of people asking low quality questions (usually in good faith), and others answering them (usually in good faith) with low quality answers before the question gets closed. [For example](https://serverfault.com/a/402937/96078). Is there any way to delete an accepted low quality answer? Even if it gets many downvotes, it will still appear in Google, and since the question is closed, there will be no other accurate or high quality answers to contrast with.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any answer can be deleted by any moderator at any time. If an answer has a negative score, then 20k+ users can vote to delete it. It takes 3 20k votes to delete. If it's really bad, then hopefully three 20k users will catch it after it's been sufficiently downvoted.

Comment: I will accept this answer as soon as the system allows me to :) I did not know that.

Comment: Mods don't need a negative score although that helps in the justification.

Comment: It really does help in the justification. Unless it's in my strong areas, I don't like hammering answers without at least one other person saying "do that". That whole err on the side of caution thing.

Comment: Wait, I didn't think that a 20k user could vote to delete just any answer, I thought it had to be negative, but the edit to my answer says otherwise. Has this changed?

Answer (score 6):

[image]

^ Yes, we do have a system in place for flagging and deal with the *heinously wrong* answers.

Comment: We do? I'm fairly sure that we have a "declined" flag reason as "Do not flag wrong answers"

Comment: If it's really bad, I see no problem in flagging and mod-hammering. You're right that if it "ordinary" wrong, the flag's getting declined.